# Print with conditions

Tags: ocaml

I make the question clearly in this question.
I have a graph like this:

```
a <-> b -> e -> f
|          |
v          v
h <------- g 
|          |
v          v  
u          k
```

There depend relation describe in the list `entries`

```
let entries = [
  ("a", ["b"; "h"]);
  ("b", ["a"; "e"]);
  ("e", ["f"; "g"]);
  ("g", ["h"; "k"]);
  ("h", ["u"]);
]
```

I extracted a list `defined` and `undefined`, the result like this:

```
let defined = ["a"; "b"; "e"; "g"; "h"; "u"]
let undefined = ["f"; "k"]
```

After computed I got a new list with their ordered:

```
let ordered = [["u"];["h"]; ["k"]; ["g"]; ["f"]; ["e"]; ["b"; "a"]]
```

I want to write a function that print the output of `ordered` in such conditions like this:

1) I want to have a function that will generate a new list in the list `ordered` if the element in `undefined` appear it'll remove it. I'm expecting a `newordered` like this:

```
newordered = [["u"]; ["h"]; ["g"]; ["e"]; ["b"; "a"]]
```

2) I want to print their depends with this conditions:

when it is just one type depend, it will print :

```
Definition name := type depend.
```

when it is a equivalance (a <-> b), it will print :

```
Inductive name1 := type depend 1
with name2 := type depend 2.
```

when it is a list of type depends, it will print:

```
Inductive name := type depend.
```

When it see the type in `undefined` list, and when it has not depend type, it will print:

```
Definition name := name.
```

and with the order of of the order in the `newordered` list

The output I'm expecting like this:

```
Definition k := k.
Definition f := f.
Definition u := u.
Definition h := u.
Inductive g := h -> k.
Inductive e := f -> g.
Inductive b := a -> e
with a := b -> h.
```

I write these functions, first I print all the elements in undefined list:

```
let print_undfined =
List.iter (fun name -> Printf.printf "\nDefinition %s := %s." name name;
      print_string "\n")undefined
```

I have a function that print the right - hand side of the entries list:

```
let defn_of =
  List.iter (fun (_, xs) -> 
    List.iter (fun t -> Printf.printf "%s" t) xs)
```

I have another function that remove the duplicate in the `ordered` list with `undefined` list

```
let rec uniquify = function
| [] -> []
| x::xs -> x :: uniquify (List.filter ((<>) x) xs)

let new_sort = uniquify (undefined @ List.flatten ordered)
```

But this list is `string list` and it added the `undefined` list int the font. So if I print my last function it will duplicate `undefined` if I choose to print all the element in `undefined` first. And I don't want that.

And I am not figure how I can write the last function with print for me the output I want at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I correct `defn_of` function to return string representation of relations of a label by looking up `entries`:

```
let defn_of label =
    try
       let (_, xs) = List.find (fun (l, ys) -> l = label) entries in
       String.concat "->" xs
    with
        Not_found -> ""
```

Second, what you returned in `new_sort` (which supposed to be `newordered`) is plainly wrong. What you really wanted is filtering out all lists with one element occuring in `undefined`:

```
let newordered = List.filter (function [x] -> List.for_all((<>) x) undefined
                                       | _ -> true) ordered
```

As usual, printing functions are based on functions in [Printf](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) module and `String.concat`.
There are two cases in your printing task:

**Case 1:** for all labels in `undefined`, use your `print_undfined` function above.

**Case 2:** for any list `xs` in `newordered`, if `xs` has only one element, that means no equivalence class exists. If `xs` has at least two elements, equivalence classes should be printed:

```
let print_defined_equivalence xs = 
    match xs with
    | [] -> ()
    | [x] -> Printf.printf "\nInductive %s := %s." x (defn_of x)
    | _ ->
        let ys = String.concat "\nwith" 
                  (List.map (fun x -> 
                     Printf.sprintf "%s := %s" x (defn_of x)) 
                        xs) in
        Printf.printf "\nInductive %s." ys
```

As a side note, I chose to handle empty list as an element of `newordered` although it didn't occur in your test case. Another thing is `entries` is traversed many times to look up elements, it should be changed to `Map` datatype, especially when `entries` is big.

Given the fact that I have stated clearly a condition for each case, your should be able to plug these functions into your program.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Honestly, I am struggling with the function to show that it is an equivalence classes or not.

Comment: Are you struggling with using `newordered` or creating `newordered`? Because two labels in a same list in `newordered` are equivalence classes.

Comment: both! function 'new_sort' above is what I write for 'newordered', but I don't want it added type of undefined list in this new list. I just know to call when it is in equivalence classes, but how about when it has 1 element? I mean the condition that check it can call when it has 1 element, and when it is an equivalence classes. This is the function I call, let print = List.iter (fun eqvclass -> print_defined_equivalence eqvclass) new_sort

Comment: Your `new_sort` is wrong. I have updated my answer to correct it. Your printing on `new_sort` should be fine now.